# How to efficiently get a collection that contains multiple nested collections

Tags: arrays, performance, typescript, collections, nested

*Title might not be the best, an improvement would be much appreciated!*

What i mean is actually very simple question:

Say i have a `School` class containing an array of `Student`s that has an array of `Notebook`s, and i want to refer all the `Notebook`s in my `School`

```
public class School{
  students: Student[];
}

public class Student{
  notebooks: Notebook[]
}
```

How should i refer to all of the Notebooks in my school?

*Looking for a more efficient way from saving all the `Notebook`s in a separate array achieved with a `for` loop..*

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the `notebooks`? There are many array functions that you could use `filter`, `some`, `every`, `forEach`, `reduce`, `map`?

Comment: @adam-beck  thanks for the quick reply. I'd like to display em together and do some CRUD on them

Comment: Didn't you confuse Javascript with Java? Javascript has no `public` keyword used, at least now. It is [reserved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Future_reserved_keywords), but not actually used yet.

Comment: @hindmost with `typescript` you can use `public` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to do with the output or each individual notebook? This function closely replicates to `for` loops without all the boilerplate.

```
school.students.forEach(function(student) {
  student.notebooks.forEach(function(notebook) {
    doSomethingWithNotebook(notebook);
  });
});

// this returns all notebooks for all students and puts it into a single (flat) array
var allNotebooks = school.students.reduce(function(collection, student) {
  return collection.concat(sudent.notebooks);
}, []);

// now you can do things like filter out only New notebooks
var newNotebooks = allNotebooks.filter(notebook => notebook.isNew);
```

Comment: A quick explanation or link for the `reduce` would be nice

Comment: The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

It's a pretty complex (but **powerful**) function of JS. There is an entire course from Egghead.io https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-introducing-reduce-transforming-arrays-functionally

Comment: Oh thats a very cool one, so the first parameter (`collection`) is the returned value from the last iteration. Alright thanks, i think that will do it :)

Comment: Yes. And you will notice I supplied an empty array as the second argument to reduce (the first argument is the callback function). This is the initial value of `reduce` and is optional. Again, it might take some time to understand but once you start using it regularly it's a game-changer.

Comment: Yeah that was my upcoming question - what do we start with? hehe thanks Adam, looks very useful when mastered :)

Comment: > If no initialValue was provided, then accumulator will be equal to the first value in the array and currentValue will be equal to the second... in my example collection is the accumulator and student is the currentValue

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, my reflex would be to look for something like an n-dimensional array/matrix, think

```
myMatrix[ [school][student][notebook[]] ]
```

(but with valid syntax), 
and then figure out how to pull myMatrix[[anything][anything][Notbooks[]]].

This would end up avoiding the for loop, but anything that's going to let you select all of the 3nested elements I'm pretty dang sure is going to be just as complex with those elements stored nested or not.

Not a definitive answer per se, but without more details on what you need, the best I can do is offer up avenues of thought.

Comment: Actually that is something to think about, because i do need em grouped and yet related to their `Student`s, But I'm not sure if it gives me better access than just keep the base hierarchy as it is